# How to add all test run inside a test plan in test rail triggered from cypress

Tags: cypress, testrail

We are using Cypress to automate UI test cases. We have recently integrated the cypress framework  with test rail. It is able to create test run in test rail.

Issue: 
We want all test run should go inside a test plan or any suite or any folder. Currently all test run are created independently(can be seen in screenshot below) in the test rail "Test Run and Results Tab" which pollutes the test rail dashboard.

Is there any one all test run should go inside a plan or any folder?

Solution I have tried:

1)I have tried providing  test plan id in the reporter option  but didn't work.

2)Have tried @architectnow/cypress-testrail-reporter as it uses Planid but seems some issue with this package. Getting error reporter not found.

[image]

Below is the cypress Test rail reporter config:

```
      "domain":"xxxxx.testrail.io",
      "username":"email",
      "password":"pass",
      "projectId":1,
      "planId":17,
      "suiteId":1,
      "runName":"Cypress Automated Test Run"
```

Appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter.

npm install cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter --save-dev

It will create one single test run and also will not be closed automatically after all spec fiels will ran.